# Xamarin / C# extending an existing class

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms

I've been learning C# for a while most recently `MVVM` but I've failed to grasp something regarding extending classes, obviously ...

In the example below, `SkiaSharp` is a Xamarin vector graphics package, I've been supplied some vector icons and I'm looking to have a reusable class to scale and color them at various points in the app

I figured if I subclassed 'SKCanvasView' then I could pass in the variables (icon, color) - all works fine when the code is in the related view but I wanted it in shared code, so I reference it like so

```
         <ContentView xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms" 
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
         xmlns:d="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms/design"
         xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
         mc:Ignorable="d"
         xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Custom"
         x:Class="NavigationIcons">

        <local:RenderSVG StyleId="F9001A"
                         Grid.Row="0"
                         Grid.Column="1"
                         HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand"
                         VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand"
                         ClassId="vector.svg" 
                         PaintSurface="OnCanvasViewPaintSurface">

        </local:RenderSVG>
```

It builds, but then it complains the method for 'PaintSurface' isn't in the view code-behind file, which of course I didn't think it needed to be if it's referencing another class

I would have assumed that `"local:SVGRender"` would mean that all code would be run from that shared class, rather than the class file behind the XAML view, but it appears not?

```
public class RenderSVG : SKCanvasView
{


    void OnCanvasViewPaintSurface(object sender, SKPaintSurfaceEventArgs args)
    {
        try
        { 
            // rendering code is here

        }
    }

}
```

The error that's being thrown is "EventHandler "Custom.RenderSVG.OnCanvasViewPaintSurface" with correct signature not found in type "NavigationIcons", so it's not even trying to look at the derived class I made

Comment: `PaintSurface` is an event, When you handle an event like you have done above it will basically create a Event Handler which will handle this event when it occurs. So basically that is what your above code seems to be doing, On the basis of my understanding of your question you do not want that what you want is for your Image to be drawn when you assign it something. So Please give us some more information about the RendeSvg class.

Comment: How does it start drawing for instance? Are you using the `ClassId` property to assign it a value if yes on that property changed are you calling the required methods to draw this Image?

Comment: Did you try to use `override` to override the event/method?

Comment: OK all apologies for not being sufficiently clear. The PaintSurface event is called when the method is in the code behind for the view. So the code works fine (which is why I didnt include it). But it's 'absent' and hence the build fails when I reference it in an external class (RenderSVG). I am wondering whether the path to the method OnCanvasViewPaintSurface needs an absolute path?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @FreakyAli said `PaintSurface` is an event. When using `SKCanvasView` inside a `ContentView`, you bind the event to a method (event handler) of the container. `SKCanvasView` will fire the event and the container method gets called.

But when you subclass `SKCanvasView` you have to override `OnPaintSurface`. Alternatively you can at some point attach the `OnCanvasViewPaintSurface` event handler to `PaintSurface` event through code (e.g. at construction) and at some point you will also need to detach it (before destruction). Overriding `OnPaintSurface` is the preferred way. For example:

```
public class RenderSVG : SKCanvasView
{
    protected override void OnPaintSurface(SKPaintSurfaceEventArgs args)
    {
        try
        { 
            // rendering code is here
        }
    }
}
```

Of course you need to remove `PaintSurface="OnCanvasViewPaintSurface"` from your XAML file:

```
<ContentView xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms" 
     xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
     xmlns:d="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms/design"
     xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
     mc:Ignorable="d"
     xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Custom"
     x:Class="NavigationIcons">

    <local:RenderSVG StyleId="F9001A"
                     Grid.Row="0"
                     Grid.Column="1"
                     HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand"
                     VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand"
                     ClassId="vector.svg">
    </local:RenderSVG>
```

Comment: So as mentioned I think I have a good idea how I'd do the latter, since I am using ViewModels quite widely now, however I am trying to understand as much of c# as I can so I'd be realy keen to try and get the override working. Would you be able to give me an example of how it might look in a situation like this? The error that's being thrown is "EventHandler "Custom.RenderSVG.OnCanvasViewPaintSurface" with correct signature not found in type "NavigationIcons", so it's not even trying to look at the derived class I made

Comment: So I did some reading and found a SO post which said you need to use virtual rather than override, because I was getting an error using override. However, there is still the build error indicated above where the XAML compiler is failing saying the view code behind doesn't contain the method - like it's still looking in the wrong place

Comment: Updated my answer. In short, `OnPaintSurface` is already a `virtual` so you just override it in your (descendant) class

Comment: Gah, ok I didn't understand how I could simply remove that reference ("PaintSurface") and expect any result but it's now partially working! The bit I'm missing now is to establish how I can get the actual instance of SKSufaceView in order to receive ClassID and StyleID? In OnCanvasViewPaintSurface it's cast from sender, how would I get same in OnPaintSurface? Thanks loads for help so far!

Comment: Never mind, I figured out what you meant about attaching the OnCanvasPaint method to PaintSurface in the constructor, works perfectly. Thanks loads